# Creating error bars in one direction, a special case

Tags: r, ggplot2

Long time lurker here.

I am plotting the predicted values from a previously run, nlme model using the output by ggpredict. I have built a line plot and want to create error bars on the points.  Though, reviewers want the error bars to only be going one direction (i.e., for the group who is higher = positive error bars, while the group who is negative gets negative error bars).  I've successfully done this with this code:

```
Q1 <- ggpredict(MODEL, c("day", "group"), 
               #ci.lvl = NA,
               type = "re")

q2 <- Q1 %>% 
  mutate(is.int = group == "Intervention",
         conf.high = ifelse(is.int, std.error, conf.high),
         conf.low = ifelse(is.int, 0, conf.low)) %>% 
  select(-is.int) %>% 
  mutate(is.cntr = group == "Control",
         conf.high = ifelse(is.cntr, 0, conf.high),
         conf.low = ifelse(is.cntr, std.error, conf.low)) %>% 
  select(-is.cntr)


    ggplot(data = q2,
           aes(x, predicted, group = group)) +
      geom_point(aes(shape = group), size = 6) +
      scale_shape_manual(values=c(19, 1)) +
      geom_line(size = 2,
                aes(linetype = group),
                color = "black") +
      scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed")) +
      geom_linerange(size = 1,
                     aes(ymin = predicted - conf.low,
                         ymax = predicted + conf.high),
                     color = "black",
                     alpha = .8) +
      labs(x = "Time",
           y = "",
           linetype = "",
           shape = "") 
      scale_y_continuous(limits =c(1500, 2000)) +
      geom_bracket(
        xmin = "PRE", xmax = c("MID1", "MID2", "MID3", "POST"),
        y.position = c(1850,1900,1950,2000), tip.length = 0.05,
        label = c("*", "**", "***", "#"), size = 1)
```

and it works well.

**however**

The reviewers would like "caps" on the end of the error bars that i've reated with `geom_linerange()`. Obviously, `geom_errorbar()` is almost purpose built to have the "caps". But, when I use it, it creates lines across my data. See pic attached for example. [image: example of bad error bars]

Thoughts??

Edit, Reproducibile data:

```
    dput(q2)
structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("PRE", "MID1", "MID2", "MID3", "POST"), class = "factor"), 
    predicted = c(1666.97185871754, 1660.27445165342, 1743.2831065274, 
    1678.48945165342, 1788.50605542978, 1637.40907049806, 1807.55826371403, 
    1639.78265640012, 1865.8766220711, 1652.91070173056), std.error = c(88.8033117577884, 
    91.257045996107, 92.9973963841595, 95.3834973421298, 95.0283457128716, 
    97.3739053806999, 95.6466346849776, 97.9142418717957, 93.3512943191676, 
    95.5735155125126), conf.low = c(0, 91.257045996107, 0, 95.3834973421298, 
    0, 97.3739053806999, 0, 97.9142418717957, 0, 95.5735155125126
    ), conf.high = c(88.8033117577884, 0, 92.9973963841595, 0, 
    95.0283457128716, 0, 95.6466346849776, 0, 93.3512943191676, 
    0), group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Intervention", "Control"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to highjack the `arrow` argument of `geom_segment()` to serve as caps, since you've already precomputed the confidence intervals. You can control with an `ifelse` whether to take the lower or higher confidence level. Example with dummy data below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Make dummy data
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1:10, 1:10),
  y = c(1:10, seq(0.5, 5, by = 0.5)),
  type = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 10)
)

# Dummy confidence intervals
df$conf.hi <- df$y * 1.1
df$conf.lo <- df$y * 0.9

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, 
                   yend = ifelse(type == "A", conf.hi, conf.lo)),
               arrow = arrow(angle = 90))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: Example for added data

Probably, the reason that it didn't turn out as the example was because the `conf.high`/`conf.low` variables were not added to the prediction.
I used the `std.error` instead of the `conf.*` variables, as I noticed these are similar values.
I got a decent plot using the following.

```
ggplot(q2, aes(x, predicted, colour = group)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, 
                   yend = predicted + ifelse(group == "Intervention", std.error, -std.error)),
               arrow = arrow(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What you produced is what I am after. Unfortunately, this doesn't work on my end. When I run the code, each group (i.e., A, B) has negative bars in addition to the positive (or vice versa for group B).

I attempted to add my reproducible data set to this cooment, but am limited by character count. The reproducible data set has been edited to my original post. Do you see any thing that would be causing my plot to still not look like yours?